# Should I throw these boards with soldering issues out?

Tags: pcb, reflow

I've just baked some boards. The first two looked normal, but upon closer inspection I noticed that paste did not melt under one chip with exposed pad package. I used a slightly different profile with 30s longer preheat and 10s longer peak (both are leaded profiles) for the rest of the boards. Now there were no issues with paste, but two capacitors from different manufacturers received a faint tint on their pads, one pink, another blue. Below are photos from first and last board.

[image: first board]

[image: last board]

Should I just throw these boards out as over-cooked? Should I replace the capacitors and see if they work? Should I just ignore the capacitors and try powering the boards?

UPDATE: for the reference, the paste was [TS391AX50](https://www.chipquik.com/datasheets/TS391AX50.pdf), about a month left on shelf life.

Comment: That tint does look strange, as if the components have aged. And the wetting is poor too, as if all the flux vaporized. Any theory about what might have caused it, bad paste? How big a batch are we talking about here?

Comment: I would power the boards, the tint might be due to paste getting all over the pad of the components. I cannot say why the first time the paste couldn't melt if it had been doing so consistently before that, but I don't think extending the heating cycle by seconds can cause these boards to be waste-worthy. Now that being said, I think you should give some context regarding your application (are these boards supposed to reach a customer? etc.) I've abused many boards temperature-wise, and most of them survived, albeit becoming ugly.

Comment: @Lundin fortunately only 10 boards. but with almost 200 components / $300 per board it is not that I am looking forward to trying again before figuring out what happened. Wetting is actually OK, it just looks that way because it is covered with hard bubbly flux residue which does not come out with isopropyl alcohol rub. The paste felt a bit on a dry side, but still within shelf life.

Comment: Why I said "it looks as if they have aged" is because I've seen a similar tint on components that had been left in a hot environment for a very long time. Nothing like a solder oven, just around 70-80°C, but over a period of many years. Those boards still worked though. I can't explain the chemistry causing it.

Comment: @YordanAleksandrov the reason I am worried about powering up is that those caps are in DC-DC power supply, so if they are damaged I may fry the entire board easily. The boards are prototypes, but they were supposed to go to ISO 7176-21 testing.

Comment: @Maple In this case, I would limit my power supply's current output and attempt to switch on one of the boards. If the PSU chip is not a fake chinese one, even in the worst case your main electronics SHOULD be protected by the chip's internal limiters. Plus, you can feel even safer if the device itself has other protection circuitry (most commerical devices do).

Comment: Just touch-up those solder points?

Comment: @YordanAleksandrov good Idea. I'll try that. The chip is [AP63203WU-7](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP63200-AP63201-AP63203-AP63205.pdf), from Diodes authorized dealer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom picture has sputtering on the solder, this happens when the flux has issues. Incorrect solder masking or using solder that is past its shelf life.

It's not great to have solder like this as sometimes the components don't solder, war with fine pitch components like a 402s or below you can get solder balls creating solder bridges.

It really depends on how much we work you want to do to get these boards back up to spec and how much inspection you want to do to make sure that they work.

I probably would not send these into a production environment but if you're just testing it would probably be acceptable if you rework the boards I've reworked boards before like this so I didn't have to make new ones, but that takes time.

Comment: So, in your opinion, the boards have an issue with solder paste and not with extended reflow time, correct? This does not explain why one capacitor turned pink and another blue. And I still don't know if it means that I could have damaged other components, like MCU or flash. What is interesting, is that over 40 other capacitors from the same Samsung series (much lower capacitance though) did not turn blue as C11 did. There are no other Murata parts (C14) on board to compare, unfortunately

Comment: The cap looks like flux issues, probably from flux vapours. I wouldn't think discoloration would be an issue. Like I said test the components and see if they're still good The whole point of good SMT practices is to avoid failures most of the time parts will be okay but if you're concerned you have to test them and that is the annoying part. I would probably get SMT tweezers and major the caps or an LCR meter and see if they're connected

Comment: Yeah, google can't get  STT right